# Extract & Filter in Cypher

Tags: filter, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to solve this problem but still it has problem.. Well, my query a bit complex because I use extract, shortpath and filter. When I try this code below, It returns filter requires where..

```
match (actor:Actor{name:"XXXX"}),(reeves:Actor{name:"YYYY"}),  
p= shortestPath ((actor)-[*..20]-(reeves))
where "Reeves, Keanu"=filter(n2 in nodes(p):n.name)
return distinct extract(n in nodes(p)|n.name) as Names;
```

but as you see there is "where" keyword.

and I tried like that

```
match (actor:Actor{name:"XXXX"}),(reeves:Actor{name:"YYYY"}),  
p= shortestPath ((actor)-[*..20]-(reeves))
WHERE NOT ALL (x IN  nodes(p)
       WHERE x.name<> "YYYY")
return distinct extract(n in nodes(p)|n.name) as Names;
```

but this time, I still get "Reeves, Keanu" name.. I want to filter this name from my result..

where am I doing a mistake?

Comment: Remember that "filter" is used to return a "filtered down" collection.

As for your question, can you clarify?  Is "YYYY" supposed to be "Reeves, Keanu" or not?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the shortest paths that contain the name "YYYY", try:

```
MATCH (actor:Actor{name:"XXXX"}), (reeves:Actor{name:"YYYY"}),  
  p = shortestPath ((actor)-[*..20]-(reeves))
WHERE any(n2 in nodes(p) WHERE n2.name="YYYY")
RETURN distinct extract(n in nodes(p) | n.name) as Names;
```

On the other hand, if you want to *ignore* the shortest paths that contain the name "YYYY":

```
MATCH (actor:Actor{name:"XXXX"}), (reeves:Actor{name:"YYYY"}),  
  p = shortestPath ((actor)-[*..20]-(reeves))
WHERE none(n2 in nodes(p) WHERE n2.name="YYYY")
RETURN distinct extract(n in nodes(p) | n.name) as Names;
```

By the way, notice how the `any` and `none` predicates internally require a `WHERE clause`.